# Python: extract text out of string

Tags: python

I have two lists.

- tvmodels.txt
- vendors.txt

In those list all tv models and tv vendors are in it.

The input on the files are as followed:

```
tvmodels.txt file
KDL40W705CBAEP
KDL55W755CBAEP
KD75XD8505BAEP
KDL40WD650BAEP
UE75H6470AWXXN

vendors.txt file
SAMSUNG
SONY
LG
PHILIPS
PANASONIC
```

When I use my script than the `mshtv['item_2_name']` returns `SAMSUNGUE75H6470LEDTV(Flat,75Zoll,FullHD,3D,SMARTTV)`

Now what I want to achieve:

1) I get any vendor out of the `vendors.txt` file in the field `mshtv['item_vendor']`. In this example this would be `SAMSUNG`

2) I get any tv model out of the `tvmodels.txt` file i the field `mshtv['item_model']`. In this example this would be `UE75H6470`.

With the tv models there's one more catch. In the `tvmodels.txt`file all tv models are in the official vendors format. For this example it's in the list as `UE75H6470AWXXN`.
The reason behind it is that some retailers are using the full tv model reference and others only partial.

If tried working with `if any` but that didn't work. I've looked around but couldn't find any other solutions. Any suggestions?

```
    import scrapy.selector 
    import urlparse
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
    from scrapy.http import Request
    from MediaMarkt.items import MediamarktItem

    models = []
    for line in open("tvmodels.txt", "r"):
        models.append(line.strip("\n\-"))
    d = {}
    for model in models:
        d[model] = True


    vendors = []
    for line in open("vendors.txt", "r"):
        vendors.append(line.strip("\n\-"))
    e = {}
    for vendor in vendors:
        e[vendor] = True


    def complete_url(string):
        return "http://www.mediamarkt.de"+ string


    def encode(str):
        return str.encode('utf8', 'ignore') 


    class MshbeSpider(Spider):
        name = "mshdetv"
        start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.de/mcs/productlist/_led-lcd-fernseher,48353,460668.html?langId=-3&searchParams=&sort=&view=&page=']

        def parse(self, response):  
            items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="products-list"]/li/div')
            for item in items:
                mshtv = MediamarktItem()
                mshtv['item_3_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0]).replace("-","")
                mshtv['item_2_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0]).replace("-","").replace(" C","C").replace(" B","B").replace(" ","")
                mshtv['item_a_link'] = item.select('.//div/h2/a/@href').extract()
                mshtv['item_4_avai'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/ul/li//text())').extract()[0])
                #mshtv['item_1_cat'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="category"]/hgroup/h1/text())').extract()[0])
                for word in mshtv['item_2_name'].split(" "):
                    if word in d:
                        mshtv['item_model'] = word
                for word in mshtv['item_2_name'].split(" "):
                    if word in e:
                        mshtv['item_vendor'] = word             
                yield mshtv


            new_link = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield Request(complete_url(new_link),callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include some sample lines from your input files.